# My iMac running Ubuntu 16.04 always lags like crazy when I open the unity search bar

Tags: 16.04, unity, mac

my **iMac 2006** is running **Ubuntu 16.04 LTS** and every time I open the search bar, the screen goes insane, lags, and of course, freezes. I really need to know how to fix this because I am just sick and tired of the insane lagging. Thanks in advance!

[Screenshot of the lag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m282w.png)

Comment: What iMac model and/or other hardware information? Please edit and post that information. In general, standard Ubuntu, Kubuntu, Ubuntu GNOME or any other variant with a modern 3D desktop environment, are **not** recommended for  old hardware. But your screenshoot also suggests an issue with graphics. The search being slow and it depending on lots of reading suggests issues with the HDD.

Comment: iMac Late 2006, used to have macOS Lion, upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: I will attempt to reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: Never mind, doesn't work

Comment: What can I do to fix this